# Problems with socket.removeAllListeners(); (socket.io)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I encounter an issue with my code when using `socket.removeAllListeners();`

I'm using express, `socket.io` and `socket.io-client`: this server is linked to another one, represented by matchmaking which is sending the information that the game has stopped.

```
var express = require('express');
var url = require('url');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var matchmaking = require("socket.io-client")('http://localhost:1610');

io.on('connection',function(socket){
var page = 'lobby';
show_page(page);
matchmaking.on('ChangePage',function(value){
//switch lobby to game
            show_page(value.Page);
});
function show_page(page){
//The user goes here to login and sends info to the matchmaking server
if(page == 'lobby')
{
  //If more than 2 players are waiting , the matchmaking server generate a game server, put the waiting players in it and sends it to this server.
}
//If the player joined a game, he's redirected here
else if(page == 'game')
{
socket.on('PlayerMove',function(value){
// The game Code 
})
matchmaking.once('END',function(value){
   //The game is ended and the user go back to lobby in the players queue where he will be put in another game
   socket.removeAllListeners("PlayerMove");
   show_page('lobby');
})
}
}
})
```

When the game is ended, the user will join another game and will pass by `(page == 'game')`where he will be affected with another listener. So the first time , the game works perfecly but then each time he joins a new server, the code inside the listenner is multiplied.
The only way I found to fix it is to make the code like that which doesn't fit with my idea.

```
socket.on('PlayerMove',function(value){
     // code inside 
}
socket.removeAllListeners("PlayerMove");
    matchmaking.once('END',function(value){
})
```

Is there any solution to my problem ?
Thanks in advance

I've finaly resolved the problem on my own : this multiplication was caused because i forgot to remove socket on the clients too.

Comment: Your code seems to be malformed - there are some parentheses missing. I don't understand the problem. "when the code is executed again because of a new server, I get 2 listeners" - does this mean the first time it's okay? How do you get two listeners when you run new server? How the server is "linked to another one"? Provide more info, as this seems like a great mismatch :)

Comment: I hope the code you pasted is a bad reduction of your actual code, because it really doesn't make much sense. As shown, the user will never execute any of the `page == 'game'` part, so it's quite difficult to help you with your problem without having the actual code you use. Have you checked the case of the `END` event? Event names are case sensitive, so if the actual event is `end` this will definitely not work. Otherwise, you could explore the option of adding the `PlayerMove` event listener immediately on connection, and route differently, rather than add it when joining a game.

Comment: Sorry i'm new in community helping so i don't know that much what to put.I'm doing my best to get my thread clear but you can ask if you need any more information. Thanxs for your help